# Selenium Python -- Message: element not visible

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to click on a href link.
I managed to get the link by

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'main.cfm')]")
```

But when I was using`element.click()`, it showed

> Message: element not visible

I am not sure why. Could it be the "==$0" in the picture? When I moved the mouse on to the text it says "Use $0 in the console to refer to this element".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath

```
//a[span[text()[contains(., 'Latest Projects')]]]
```

this is to select parent link of 'span' element which has substring text 'Latest Projects'.

Comment: Then please mark the answer as correct if the solution worked for your case.

Comment: sorry thought i did.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of @Shoaib Akhtar is right, You can also use this xpaths

```
//span[contains(text(),'Latest Projects')]

//span[contains(@class,'uppercase')][contains(text(),'Latest Projects')]
```